# Yii 2 - Class not found after installing with composer

Tags: yii2, composer-php

After installing a package via composer, I'm unable to use it because of an error.

```
Class 'PHPShopify\ShopifySDK' not found
```

I'm using the following code

```
$shopify = new \PHPShopify\ShopifySDK($config);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try composer dump-autoload

Comment: does the class exist on the same path and the namespace match?

Comment: There is no one PHPShopify\ShopifySDK package